# DataList binding : "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datalist

I'm trying to bound a DataList control with selected data from a SQL Table:

```
     private void ShowPossiblePurchases(string CategoryName)
{

    string selectSQL = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Menu WHERE CategoryName=@CategoryName ORDER BY NEWID()";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", CategoryName);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    DataList DataList1 = (DataList)lgnView.FindControl("DataList1");

    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataList1.DataSource = reader;
        DataList1.DataBind();

        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label lblError = (Label)lgnView.FindControl("lblError");
        lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

When i run this code, i get "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

My previous version of the method was this:

```
    private void ShowPossiblePurchases(string CategoryName)
```

{

```
string selectSQL = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Menu WHERE CategoryName=@CategoryName ORDER BY NEWID()";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", CategoryName);
SqlDataReader reader;

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataSet.Tables.Add("Products");


myDataSet.Tables["Products"].Columns.Add("ProductID");
myDataSet.Tables["Products"].Columns.Add("CategoryID");
myDataSet.Tables["Products"].Columns.Add("ProductName");
myDataSet.Tables["Products"].Columns.Add("Price");

DataList DataList1 = (DataList)lgnView.FindControl("DataList1");

try
{
    connection.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {

        DataRow rowNew = myDataSet.Tables["Products"].NewRow();
        rowNew["ProductID"] = reader["ProductID"];
        rowNew["CategoryID"] = reader["CategoryID"];
        rowNew["ProductName"] = reader["ProductName"];
        rowNew["Price"] = reader["Price"];
        myDataSet.Tables["Products"].Rows.Add(rowNew);
    }

    DataList1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["Products"];
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Label lblError = (Label)lgnView.FindControl("lblError");
    lblError.Text = ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think you can bind to the reader directly like that, you'll probably need to copy the results into another collection and use that as the data source

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on your connection.Open and then step through and see where you are getting that error.

Comment: @w69rdy : i've edited my first post (now you can also read my previous version of the method which used a DataSet for binding the DataList control). Even that version, was producing the mentioned error.

Comment: i think the error is on a second open connection... how and where you call ShowPossiblePurchases ? use async method or static method? if yes try to check the connection status before open ... if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to First Close the connection than reader

Comment: However, i don't know why i need to do a supplementary call to the close() method when i regularly close the connection in the 'finally' block.

Comment: Actually your "finally" run at the end of the function so you can write your reader close in finally after the connection close

Comment: I meant the other "finally" blocks, elsewhere in the code...Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the connection was closed first:

```
If ((cmd.Connection.State And System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) _
         <> System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
    cmd.Connection.Open()
End If
```

C#:

```
if (((cmd.Connection.State & System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring connection?

It seems like you are declaring it outside of the code provided and opening the connection somewhere else before hand.

To avoid trying to open it twice, you can put in a simple check to see if the connection is open...

```
if (conn == null || conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                OpenDBConnection();
```

Comment: The connection object is declared in a SuperClass from which child-classes, like the one containing the above method, can inherit.